# How would you describe the following futuristic skyline of Toronto and its destruction as it is happening?

Tags: creative-writing

I'm just trying to understand how I should properly describe my "futuristic" Toronto before an alien invasion and after an alien invasion or attack.

Images attached to give help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0q7Z.jpg

Comment: I know how I would describe it, but I'm not in your story so it'd just be an impersonal description. **Pick the POV who has the highest stakes** (protagonist?), give them some feelings and opinions about the city before, and some opinions and feelings watching it be destroyed. The character with the highest stakes is the person most invested in the city's well-being, the person with family and home there, the person who will suffer the greatest personal loss.... If you don't have such a character– idk, use a lot of adjectives I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is you don't need much detail. Don't describe the fall of each and every building. You can describe one or two of the most notable ones, but then just quickly describe the overall way the alien attack worked. Did they bomb it with smaller individual explosions? Did they just blow up the things like Independence Day? Did they just run a giant flattening plow across it and push it into the ocean? Did they crash a spaceship into the city and squash it like a big bug? However it happened, describe that rather than the individual destructions of buildings.

Also, keep it short unless your character is in the middle of it. Then time would slow down and make it somewhat off. But otherwise, keep it as short and sudden as possible. Describe the aftermath, not the actual destruction.